# AR face database : The original conversion of .raw files into other format

Tags: image, imagemagick

I have successfully downloaded and unzipped the .raw files from the set. But  i am having problem with the convert command

```
    $convert -size 768X576 -depth 8 -interlace plane rgb:m-001-1.raw m-001-1.bmp
```

As i am converting it is giving yellowish background image as seen in photo. But the image in AR face database with RGB format have white background.

Can anyone tell what is the problem?

the photo in raw format in database is of 24 bit depth.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The fact that the face is recognisable in its form indicates that you have the sizes and bit-depth and interlace correct.

The fact that it is yellow when it should be white indicates that the blue channel is *"unhappy"*. If you delete the current blue channel, and duplicate the red channel and use that as blue, it comes out presumably closer to the original:

```
convert https://i.stack.imgur.com/knQkT.png -separate -delete 2  -clone 0 -combine result.png
```

[image]

My guess is that you have an old ImageMagick version and that you should probably avoid `BMP` format - maybe consider using NetPBM's `PAM` format instead - as it is easier to process.

[NetPBM format link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netpbm_format)

To check your IM version use,

```
identify -version
Version: ImageMagick 6.9.2-4 Q16 x86_64 2015-10-29 http://www.imagemagick.org
Copyright: Copyright (C) 1999-2015 ImageMagick Studio LLC
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but i am very keen to retain the color of the face, it is the main objective of the problem.

Comment: So which IM version are you using? And can you share the raw file?

Comment: It didnt work since it is changing the primitive skin color. But I have made it work using cropped image from there database . Thanks BTW :)